# How to detect user screenshot action in flutter？

Tags: android, ios, flutter

How can I detect if the user creating a screenshot?

I do not care about the capture pictures, I just want to know when and where user creating the screenshot

How can I detect this in the flutter app?

Comment: Simple, write a plugin to listen for a button press, have pre defined screenshot action for different oem and bind your action for each of them, and there you go, once any action matches u have successfully detected it. Thank me later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this plugin, it might be what you are looking for: https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot_callback

In order to accomplish what you are looking for from the README:

```dart
import 'package:screenshot_callback/screenshot_callback.dart';

ScreenshotCallback screenshotCallback = ScreenshotCallback();

screenshotCallback.addListener(() {
  //Void funtions are implemented
  print('detect screenshot');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

try
https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot_callback

dependencies:
screenshot_callback: ^1.1.3

```
 void init() async {
await initScreenshotCallback();
```

}

//It must be created after permission is granted.

```
 Future<void> initScreenshotCallback() async {
screenshotCallback = ScreenshotCallback();

screenshotCallback.addListener(() {
  setState(() {
    text = "Screenshot callback Fired!";
  });
});

screenshotCallback.addListener(() {
  print("We can add multiple listeners ");
});
```

}

Comment: Hey there, what exactly do you mean with after permission is granted? When I use the package and upload it to AppStoreConnect, I always get a rejection with errors that don't even make sense. For example, Missing Purpose string for NSContactsUsageDescription, which obviously has nothing to do with a screenshot tracker